# NSWindow tab bar is hidden even with multiple windows in the tab group

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nstitlebaraccessoryviewcontroller

I'm trying to add tabs to an old codebase, and followed along the documentation. But the tab bar remains hidden, even with multiple windows in the tab group: The menu *Window > Show Previous Tab* and *Window > Show Next Tab* work as expected.

With a breakpoint after:

```
self.window?.addTabbedWindow(newWindow, ordered: .above)
newWindow.orderFront(self.window)
newWindow.makeKey()
```

The tab bar is visible, until I continue the breakpoint.

Inspecting the `NSWindow.tabGroup.tabBarVisible` before and later also has the tab bar set as visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the tab bar is implemented as a *NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController* and is part of the `NSWindows.titlebarAccessoryViewControllers`.

The problem was we also used a *NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController* in our app, and removed it by iterating **all** `NSWindows.titlebarAccessoryViewControllers` and removing each one.